# blocking packets larger then specific size with pf

Tags: freebsd, pfsense, pf

Is there a way with pf to block specific type of packets larger than specific size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIC, `pf` can't do this. You can use `ipfw`'s `iplen` option:

```
 iplen len-list
         Matches IP packets whose total length, including header and data,
         is in the set len-list, which is either a single value or a list
         of values or ranges specified in the same way as ports.
```